# Vector in GCC 4.4.7 Vs GCC 4.9.2

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I have a code like below.

```
void func() 
{
    typedef map<pair<uint,ulong>, pair<int,int> > MyMap;
    MyMap myMap;
    vector<MyMap::value_type> mapVector;
    //...
    for(MyMap::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++)
    {
        //if(...)
            mapVector.push_back(*it);
    }
    //...
}
```

It compiles fine with -std=gnu++11 option in GCC 4.9.2, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W38hsTFKNJrjp2Q9) but fails with -std=gnu++0x option in GCC 4.4.7, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tXIkIL3j8pZ7segu). The failure is in operator= on const pair. So how does it work with GCC 4.9.2? Can someone shed light on this difference? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did version 4.4.7 implement move-semantics?

Comment: From the release notes for 4.4: "Improved experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x". Note "experimental" and "upcoming".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the implementation of GCC 4.4.7's `vector::push_back`; I've added some comments:

```
void
push_back(const value_type& __x)
{
  // Do we still have some space left in the vector?
  if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
    {
      // Yes, some space left. Just construct new element in the existing space.
      this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish, __x);
      ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    }
  else
    // No space left, we need to allocate.
    _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
}
```

The function used here in case no space is left is `_M_insert_aux`. Note that we supply `end()` as an argument. The function `_M_insert_aux` can insert to *any* position inside the vector. This is important: If we insert anywhere other than the end, we need to move elements. Ex. how to insert `d` at position 3:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c|e|f| | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

move f one right:
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c|e|-|f| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

move e one right:
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c|-|e|f| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

place d:
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c|d|e|f| |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The first move-operation is a move-construct (you move to a position where there's no object). The second move-operation is a move-assign (you move to a position where there's a moved-from object). The placement is also a move-assignment, there also has been an object at the same place before.

Here's the start of `_M_insert_aux`, somewhat simplified:

```cpp
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
    template<typename... _Args>
      void
      vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
      _M_insert_aux(iterator __position, _Args&&... __args)
    {
      // if there's space left for the new element
      if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
        {
          // move the last element over by 1 (move-construct)
          this->_M_impl.construct(this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                                  _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*(this->_M_impl._M_finish
                                                  - 1)));
          ++this->_M_impl._M_finish;
          // safety copy of argument, in case argument refers into the vector
          _Tp __x_copy = __x;

          // move-assign all elements over until the __position
          _GLIBCXX_MOVE_BACKWARD3(__position.base(),
                                  this->_M_impl._M_finish - 2,
                                  this->_M_impl._M_finish - 1);
 
          // move-assign new element to correct position
          *__position = _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        }
```

which implements the algorithm depicted above. Note that this is the case where we *do* have enough space. In `push_back`, we never call `_M_insert_aux` if there is space left. However, this code path must still compile.

---

A map creates nodes in a tree. These nodes are `pair<const key, value>`. Why const? Because the placement of the node in the tree depends on the value of the key. If you change that key, the element is at a wrong place, which destroys the data structure invariants.

Therefore, `MyMap::value_type` is also a `pair<const key, value>`, in your case `pair< const pair<uint,ulong>, pair<int,int> >`.

Anyway, a `pair<const key, value>` is not assignable, since you can't change the first element. Therefore, the move-assignments in `_M_insert_aux` fail to compile.

---

The way gcc 4.7 implements `push_back` is not optimal, because that code path in `_M_insert_aux` exists and enforces that the value type must be move-assignable. This is not required from a theoretical point of view: If you insert only at the end, you insert to a place where there's no object yet. Hence you call a (move) constructor, not a (move-)assignment operator.

The C++11 Standard also does not allow the compiler/library to make that requirement. Therefore, more recent GCC versions have a smarter implementation of `push_back` which avoids trying to compile move-assignment from `push_back`.

Note that you also run into a quirk of class templates: Class templates are like factories that generate classes. Their member function bodies are generated on-demand. That is, you have to call `vector<yourtype>::push_back` somewhere in your code for this function to be generated ("instantiated"). `vector<yourtype>::insert` would never compile, because it tries the same assignment to a `pair<const key, value>`. But as long as you don't call `vector<yourtype>::insert`, it does not matter.

So, for a type which is non-assignable, you can still use `vector<yourtype>`. But you can only call those member functions which don't use assignment. In GCC 4.4, `push_back` compiles an assignment even though it is never used. In more recent versions, `push_back` make no direct nor indirect use of assignment.